# How memory management really works?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management, ram, segment

I've been learning about windows RAM memory managemant. I have read several articles and still have two big important and confusing question: 
1. Is the division to segments done on the memory as whole, or is it done only with each running process separately? Does it work the same in every OS?
2. When a process is preparing to run, who decides the amount of memory for each segment it will get?

I am very confused. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, I make the presumption that your usage of the term SEGMENT refers to the division of the code (i.e program section) and not the now obsolete SEGMENT as used in Intel's bastardized memory management for 16 and 32 bit processing.

If so

1. Is the division to segments done on the memory as whole, or is it done only with each running process separately?

Segmentation is only a directive to the linker that may be passed on to the program loader. Once the program executes there are no segments any longer. You just have memory pages with common attributes.

2. Does it work the same in every OS?

Segmentation will be a function of the capabilities of the linker that in turn will be a function of the operating system.

3. When a process is preparing to run, who decides the amount of memory for each segment it will get?

The linker.